# install CUDA10.1

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I thought that installing cuda was easy until i had to uninstall an old version and install a new one..

I first uninstalled the old version, which is 7.5 deb and then installed cuda10.1 with the instructions provided on the developer website.

Now the problem I have is when I type in

```
nvcc --version,
```

it says **bash: **/usr/bin/nvcc: No such file or directory.****

If I type in

```
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

it says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cuda is already the newest version (10.2.89-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 135 not upgraded.
```

It is neither the 10.1 version i try to install, nor the old 7.5 i uninstalled.
If I try to do:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

it says that no cuda is installed..

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'nvidia-cuda-toolkit' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 135 not upgraded.
```

I am basically in a loophole that i couldn't install nor uninstall..
Simply as that, but i could not fix it. As I checked, I have a cuda folder under /usr/local, but it has a link on it and does not let me go in, and its name is white...(I already linked my lib path to it, but it does not work..)

Could someone point out where might be wrong in this case?Really appreciate any help!Scratching my head right now...